# Extract house address city and zip from an address in Python

Tags: python, api, google-maps, maps

I have variable address strings such as this:

```
1234 Maple Ave. Queens, NY 11011
```

This format varies from string to string so I can use simple string parsing/splitting.
Is there any way I can connect to google maps or some other api that will look up the address and give me all the address units separately?

Ideally I should be able to do something like:

```
>> address = "1234 Maple Ave. Queens, NY 11011"
>> data = maps_api.extract_data(address)
>> print data.house_number
>> 1234 Maple Ave. 
>> print data.city
>> Queens
>> print data.state
>> NY
>> print data.zip
>> 11011
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems perfect for [googlemaps api](http://py-googlemaps.sourceforge.net/).

```py
import googlemaps
import pprint
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(<your-api-key>)
address = "1234 Maple Ave. Queens, NY 11011"

result = gmaps.geocode(address)
pprint.pprint(result)
```

This produces:

```
[{'address_components': [{'long_name': 'Maple Avenue',
                          'short_name': 'Maple Ave',
                          'types': ['route']},
                         {'long_name': 'Queens',
                          'short_name': 'Queens',
                          'types': ['political',
                                    'sublocality',
                                    'sublocality_level_1']},
                         {'long_name': 'Queens County',
                          'short_name': 'Queens County',
                          'types': ['administrative_area_level_2',
                                    'political']},
                         {'long_name': 'New York',
                          'short_name': 'NY',
                          'types': ['administrative_area_level_1',
                                    'political']},
                         {'long_name': 'United States',
                          'short_name': 'US',
                          'types': ['country', 'political']},
                         {'long_name': '11355',
                          'short_name': '11355',
                          'types': ['postal_code']}],
  'formatted_address': 'Maple Ave, Queens, NY 11355, USA',
  'geometry': {'bounds': {'northeast': {'lat': 40.7568371, 'lng': -73.8257325},
                          'southwest': {'lat': 40.7532547, 'lng': -73.8356575}},
               'location': {'lat': 40.7545838, 'lng': -73.8304485},
               'location_type': 'GEOMETRIC_CENTER',
               'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 40.7568371,
                                          'lng': -73.8257325},
                            'southwest': {'lat': 40.7532547,
                                          'lng': -73.8356575}}},
  'partial_match': True,
  'place_id': 'ChIJsdNKew1gwokRxRSYip5FkAw',
  'types': ['route']}]
```

You'll need an api key though: for that, follow [these directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/get-started/).

Alternative there seems to be [pygeocoder](http://code.xster.net/pygeocoder/wiki/Home) or geopy (which lets you choose OpenStreetMap and Bing).